# VBA Iterate through a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through a filtered table, and print the values of 3 columns. I want them to print with each row as a set (supplier, plant, price). This is the code I have so far.

```
For Each Row In Union(Range("TblRawData[Supplier]"), Range("TblRawData[plant]"), Range("TblRawData[price]")).Rows
    If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
          Debug.Print Row.Value
    End If
Next Row
```

This code prints all the suppliers, then all the plants, then all the prices. Instead of each row being a set.

```
Code Results:        Desired Result:
supplier1            supplier1, plant1, $1.50
supplier2            supplier2, plant2, $2.00
supplier3            supplier3, plant3, $3.00
plant1
plant2
plant3
$1.50
$2.00
$3.00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach worked for me using `ListRows` and simple variable construction.

*(forgive `a`, `b`, `c` variable names in this case)*

```
Option Explicit

Sub printRows()

    Dim rawData As ListObject
    Set rawData = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("TblRawData") 'change sheet name as needed

    Dim lr As ListRow
    For Each lr In rawData.ListRows

        If lr.Range(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

            Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
            a = lr.Range(1, rawData.ListColumns("Supplier").Index).Value
            b = lr.Range(1, rawData.ListColumns("plant").Index).Value
            c = Format(lr.Range(1, rawData.ListColumns("price").Index).Value, "$#,###.00")

            Dim output As String
            output = a & ", " & b & ", " & c

            Debug.Print output

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted. Yes, in OP, iteration was cell by cell down the columns... So yeah, this is the way to do it and scrap `Union` altogether.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you! just curious, is there a reason you declared the variables inside the loop?

Comment: @J.Doe doing that has no effect on the scoping of variables (`Dim` is not an executable statement), but declaring variables right where you're using them makes it 1) much harder to end up with unused variables and 2) much easier to later take that loop body and refactor it into its own scope.

Comment: @J.Doe - what Mathieu Guindon said :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I would also add it makes it easier to know exactly what the variable type is - because you are using it right where you declare it.

Answer (score 3):

`Debug.Print` implicitly writes a carriage return / "new line". You'll want to use (`;`) control characters here, inside the loop, to prevent it - and with a comma (`,`) you can align the values with tabulations (no need to actually output a comma):

```
Debug.Print Row.Value,; '<~ that semicolon is important!
```

And at each new `Row`:

```
Debug.Print '<~ no semicolon will append the carriage return so next iteration outputs to a new line
```

In other words:

```vb
For Each Row In Union(Range("TblRawData[Supplier]"), Range("TblRawData[plant]"), Range("TblRawData[price]")).Rows
    If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
          Debug.Print Row.Value,;
    End If
    Debug.Print
Next Row
```

Should output something like this:

```
supplier1      plant1    $1.50
supplier2      plant2    $2.00
supplier3      plant3    $3.00
```

Comment: @ScottHoltzman #FunFact: the behavior of `Debug.Print` mimicks `PRINT` statements of the olden days! Was super useful when your entire UI was made with ASCII characters =)

Comment: I get a run-time error when I try this, `Debug.Print Row.Value, ;` (the IDE adds a space between comma and semi-colon)

Comment: @NickSlash hm, works exactly as expected here (the VBE adding spaces is normal)

Comment: Potential problem... if those table columns are contiguous, then `Debug.Print Row.Value` will throw a type mismatch, because `Row` will be a multi-cell range. I'd use `.Cells` on the end of `Union`.

Comment: @BigBen ah, makes sense, yes. I was assuming the `Row` range would be a single cell. TBH the whole loop smells funny, OP seems to be working with a `ListObject`, but works with `Range` without leveraging the `ListObject` API. Iterating `ListRows` would be much simpler I think.

Comment: ^^^^^ This..... Though it must be a thing for people to not like the `ListObject` API and just finagle it with `Range` calls... definitely answered a question recently where OP did *not* want to use `ListObject` at all.

Comment: I'm open to using ListObject, I'll look into how to do that. The problem with this is that the Union takes all the values from each column one by one. So it does all supplier, then all the plant, then all the prices

Comment: @J.Doe - Yes. It does, because if you read it, it's doing *exactly* what is asked of it :). I will try to write up `ListObject` approach below.